# NodeJS - showing different content for logged in or not users

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I'm trying to show defferent content for logged in and not users on one page.

Here is the code I use for generating / page:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    if (!checkSession(req, res)) {
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            title: 'FrontSpeak - blog-based social network'
       })
    } else {
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            title: 'autrhorized'
        })
    }
})
```

checkSession function:

```
function checkSession(req, res) {
if (req.session.user_id) {
    db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({
            _id: new ObjectID(req.session.user_id)
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (user) {
                req.currentUser = user;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

loggin function:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    db.collection("users", function (err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, doc) {
            if (doc && doc.password == req.body.password) {
                console.log("user found");
                req.session.user_id = doc._id;
            }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

So, it doesn't seems to be working. However, I think this is not the best way to display different content. May be there are some more elegant ways to do this? Thank you!

**UPDATE:** New login function:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    db.collection("users", function (err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, doc) {
            console.log('found user');
            if (doc && doc.password == req.body.password) {
                req.session.user_id = doc._id;
                res.redirect('/');
            };
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    res.redirect('/');  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of trying to apply the traditional synchronous model to Node's asynchronous callback-driven model.

After your database query completes, you return `true`, but you're just returning to the database driver.  `checkSession` returned a long time ago.  Since that function returns *undefined* if there is a `session.user_id` (and `false` if there isn't), the login check will *always* evaluate false.

Instead, you can use Brandon's suggestion to make `checkSession` asynchronous, or I recommend implementing a middleware function:

```
function checkLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user_id) {
        db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
            if (err) return next(err); // handle errors!
            collection.findOne({
                _id: new ObjectID(req.session.user_id)
            }, function (err, user) {
                if (user) {
                    req.currentUser = user;
                } else {
                    req.currentUser = null;
                }
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        req.currentUser = null;
        next();
    }
}
```

Now you have two ways of using your middleware function.  If you want to check for a user on every request, just add it to the app:

```
app.use(checkLogin);
```

Now every single request will have a `req.currentUser`, but you incur the performance hit of fetching login state from the database for every request.  Alternatively, if you only need user information for certain requests, stick the function in the route:

```
app.get('/', checkLogin, function(req, res) {
    if (req.currentUser) {
        // logged in
    } else {
        // not
    }
});
```

You can read more about this in [the Express docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware).

Comment: Well, thanks, I know about middleware, it's a perfect solution. But there is a problem: if checkLogin returns null, then get() wont execute. And I need to display content both to logged and to unlogged users.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all what `checkLogin` returns. Think of it this way: when the `GET` request for `/` comes in, `checkLogin` runs first (since it's first in the list of callbacks). It fires off a DB query, and then the function returns nothing. When the DB call completes, the callback fires, assigns to `req`, and then calls `next`.  `next` is the magic sauce: it is how Express calls the next route handler, in this case the anonymous function in the `app.get(...)` line. Now in your anonymous route handler function, you can just check `req.currentUser == null` and render the appropriate view.

Comment: Does it matter that Node is not able to find session property of req?

Comment: Moved app.use(checkLogin); out of app.configure(function () { } and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you have to make sure that your middleware function runs *after* the Session middleware.  Middleware functions run in the order they're added, so if your function is added before the Session function, obviously `req.session` won't exist yet when your function is called.

Comment: Huh, one more question, if it's possible please. I'm not quite familiar with this async coding style. I've updated my login function in the original post, however I feel it's not correct. While collection.findOne() will be processing, one of two redirects would be trigged. I mean, Node will launch findOne() function and wont wait white it will do something - is will just redirect. Yeah? How can I fix it?

Comment: and without return; it gives back Error: Can't set headers after they are sent :) But it can be explained: the second res.redirect() launches BEFORE collection.find() sets a session, I think...

Comment: Yep, you don't really need all those `res.redirect`s.  The physically last redirect executes first, before your DB query completes.  At that point, it doesn't matter what happens in the DB since you've already ended the HTTP request.  Remember, async calls *return immediately* and control passes to the next statement, which will be after the end of the stuff in the callback function.  Control comes back to your callback function later.  Get rid of the 1st and 3rd (in physical order) `res.redirect()` calls and you should be good to go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13533/discussion-between-ilya-rusanen-and-josh3736)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `checkSession` as a synchronous function by checking its return value, but `checkSession` cannot be synchronous because it depends on asynchronous functionality, namely the callback here: `db.collection('users', function (err, collection) ...`. You'll need to modify `checkSession` to be async:

```
function checkSession(req, res, callback) {
if (req.session.user_id) {
    db.collection('users', function (err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({
            _id: new ObjectID(req.session.user_id)
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (user) {
                req.currentUser = user;
                callback(true);
            } else {
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    });
} else {
    callback(false);
}
}
```

and then use it asynchronously in your request handler:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    checkSession(req, res, function(isUser) {
      if (!isUser) {
          res.render('index.ejs', {
              title: 'FrontSpeak - blog-based social network'
         })
      } else {
          res.render('index.ejs', {
              title: 'autrhorized'
          })
      }
    });
})
```